# How to set negative tax in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am `magento developer` working on version 1.7 i have did so much googling but didn't found default `magento` add tax in total price but i want to reduce tax from total price but did find solution how i can do this

```
Please anyone tell me how i can set negative tax price in magento
```

Comment: see this answer and see if it helps. it's for magento 1.4 but it might be similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008361/magento-deduct-tax-at-checkout-for-most-countries

Comment: yes i read this post but this is not working